# Filtering and rearranging very large dictionary array without pandas

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, nested

I have a very large dictionary array that looks like this:

```
masterArray =[{'value': '-1', 'product': 'product1', 'Customer': 'customer1', 
'Sensor': 'sensor1', 'Date': '20170302', 'type': 'type1', 'ID': '100'}, 
{'value': '20', 'product': 'product1', 'Customer': 'customer1',  
'Sensor': 'sensor1','Date': '20170302', 'type': 'type2', 'ID': '100'},
{'value': '0', 'product': 'product1', 'Customer': 'customer1',  
'Sensor': 'sensor1', 'Date': '20170302', 'type': 'type1', 'ID': '101'}, 
{'value': '-5', 'product': 'product1', 'Customer': 'customer1',  
'Sensor': 'sensor1', 'Date': '20170302', 'type': 'type2', 'ID': '101'}]
```

I need to be able to print out individual csvs for each day, product, sensor, and customer, with the first column as the ID #s and the types as the rest of the columns with the value as the data filled in the rows.

```
ID, type1, type2
100, -1, 20
101, 0, -5
```

I also created a date set and a 'combination' set to gather unique dates and combinations of product, sensor, and customer.

Unfortunately I am not allowed to get the pandas library installed, although I think what I want to do would be done by this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(masterArray)
df.head()
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['ID'], values=['value'], columns=['type'])


for date in dateset:
#filter for date
    pqd = pivot.query('Date == date')

for row in comboset:
    #filter for each output
    pqc = pqd.query('Customer == row[0] & product == row[1] & sensor == row[2]')

    outputName = str(row[0] + '_' + date + '_' + row[1] + '_' + row[2] + '.csv')
    filepath = os.path.join(path, outputName)
    pqc.to_csv(filepath) #print
```

Currently my pandas-less idea is changing my masterArray into a huge nested dictionary (I create masterArray myself from other input csv files) but I am not sure if this is the most efficient way or not. I also don't know how best to set up the logic for that large of a nested dictionary. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably try something like this:

```
data_dict = {}
for each in masterArray:
    if not data_dict.has_key(each['ID']):
        data_dict[each['ID']] = []
    data_dict[each['ID']].append({each['type']: each['value']})
```